# What is an easy way to center a SwiftUI view's anchor point?

Tags: swiftui

I want to modify the anchor point of a view without knowing or calculating the size of the view. Currently I have this:

```
    Text("").font(.system(size: 60))
```

How do I center the anchor point?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the `fixedSize()` modifier so that the view maintains it's preferred size, ignoring it's parent view's sizing suggestion.
2. Add a `frame` modifier with 0 *height* and *width*. This wraps the text in a parent view. Use it to position it's child with `alignment: .center`.

```
    Text("").font(.system(size: 60))
      .fixedSize()
      .frame(width: 0, height: 0, alignment: .center)
```

Comment: What is the difference, if you don't use zero sized frame? Do you experienced different position? Please show us some example ...

Comment: Gill, you didn't change the center anchor applying zero sized frame ...

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer to this question.